# Understanding convergence in space of continuous functions on an open set

Tags: complex-analysis, metric-spaces

I am reading Conway's Complex Analysis and chapter $7$ talks about the space of continuous functions on an open set $G \subset \mathbf{C}$ into a metric space $(\Omega,d)$, denoted by $C(G,\Omega)$. The topology is later introduced as follows:

A set $U \in C(G,\Omega)$ is open if and only if for each $f \in U$ there exists a compact set $K$ and a $\delta >0$  such that $\{g: \sup_{z \in K} d(f(z),g(z))<\delta\} \subset U$.

Using an exhaustion of $G$ by compact sets $K_n$ and letting $\rho_n(f,g)=\sup_{z \in K_n} d(f(z),g(z))$ we get a metric $\rho$ on $C(G,\Omega) $ where $$\rho(f,g)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^n}\frac{\rho_n(f,g)}{1+\rho_n(f,g)}$$

Building on that is the following true for convergence in $C(G,\Omega)$?

Let $ \epsilon >0$ be arbitrary. Then $\rho(f,g)<\epsilon$ if and only if for each compact set $K$ in $G$, there exists a $\delta>0$ such that $\sup_{z \in K} d(f(z),g(z))<\delta$.

Answer (score 2):

That cannot be true: "for each compact $K \subset G$ there is $\delta > 0$ such that $\sup_{z\in K}d(f(z),g(z)) < \delta$" is always true (you are saying that $d(f(z),g(z))$ is bounded on $K$), so you are saying "$\rho(f,g)<\epsilon$ for every $\epsilon>0$", i.e., $\rho(f,g)=0$ for every $f,g$. That's clearly false.

An alternative would be this: "$\rho(f,g) < \epsilon$ iff $\sup_{z\in K}d(f(z),g(z)) < \epsilon$ for every $K\subset G$ compact". This is also false, because the first terms of the sum $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^n}\frac{\rho_n(f,g)}{1+\rho_n(f,g)}$ could be smaller than $\epsilon$ and compensate for the others being a bit larger. The point is that none of the terms can be too large if $\rho(f,g)$ is small.

What *is* true is that $\rho(f_n,f) \to 0$ iff $\sup_{z\in K} d(f_n(z), f(z)) \to 0$ for every $K \subset G$ compact.